# Excel, Return a color depending on two other cells text

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, formatting, conditional-formatting

I need to do an analysis in Excel and I would like to color a cell depending on the text of two other cells. I have to do it for a quite big table, therefore I need a way to not do it manually for each cell.

As a summary, you will see below what I'm looking for: For example Very High, Very high, I need column E in Red

[See what i need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DaIvS.png)

I would be very grateful if you can help me, I'm quite frustrated with this formatting.

Regards

Comment: Have you looked into conditional formating? That's exactly the kind of thing it does.

Answer (score 0):

You will three conditional formatting rules.

First highlight all the cell manually yellow, this will be the default color if none of the rules apply.

The rules are as follow:

Orange:

```
 =AND(COUNTIFS($A2:$B2,"Medium")=1,COUNTIFS($A2:$B2,"*High*")=1)
```

Red:

```
=COUNTIFS($A2:$B2,"*High*")=2
```

Blue:

```
=OR(AND(COUNTIFS($A2:$B2,"Low") =1,COUNTIFS($A2:$B2,"Medium")=1),COUNTIFS($A2:$B2,"Low") =2)
```

Then make sure the rules are in the correct order and that the Stop If True is check on all three rules in the Rules Manager:

[image]

[image]

Comment: This does not match exactly what the OP posted. If you look carefully, the  “Medium-Medium” highlighting should be yellow, not blue. It is however, very close, and may be close enough for the OP’s purpose

Comment: @Trenly yeah noticed that also.  it is fixed.